How to make all the values of column in groupby in Pandas equal the first value of the same column
A bit new to this, but im sure there is a way to make all the values of a column in pandas group by equal the first value of the same column.
what i have is this
[Initial Table [1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Kn7ViRGy.png
what i want is this
[final table][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/19bHzhg3.png

Please read [ask] and make sure to provide a [mre], images of code/data are not acceptable.
